# Java application on windows server possibility?

Tags: java, windows-server-2008, neo4j

I'd like to know if it is possible to have this application ([neo4j](http://blog.neo4j.org/2010/04/neo4j-rest-server-part1-get-it-going.html)) running on windows server 2008 alongside an asp.net mvc application. Reason for this, I need to access the graph database (neo4j) which provides a RESTful service from my mvc application. How would I go about setting up this architecture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the website you linked to the application is self-contained (no Tomcat etc required). So just installing the Windows package and following the instructions here ([for starting the service](http://wiki.neo4j.org/content/Getting_Started_REST#For_Windows)) should suffice.

Comment: He may need to change the default port number of `neo4j` to avoid colliding with (I guess) IIS.  But that should not be difficult.

Comment: Instructions for how to change the port are found at http://wiki.neo4j.org/content/Getting_Started_REST#Configure_port